# How to call a web method on a web service using HTTPWebRequest?

Tags: .net, web-services

When using an HTTPWebRequest object to call a web service, and supply the wsdl parameter, I get the description page ok.

```
Dim req As Net.HttpWebRequest
Dim resp As Net.HttpWebResponse
Dim sr As IO.StreamReader
Dim text As String

req = Net.WebRequest.Create("http://www.mysite.com/DS.asmx?wsdl") ' works '
resp = req.GetResponse
sr = New IO.StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream)
text = sr.ReadToEnd
```

However, when I attempt to call one of the methods using the reference showing as the soapAction, I get (404) Not Found.

```
req = Net.WebRequest.Create("http://mysite.com/DS/StaffList") ' fails '
```

Is there a difference in the way a method should be called that I'm missing? Am I misinterpreting the structure of the address?

Note: The service works fine if I set a standard WebReference in the Visual Studio project and call the method on the WebService object, so the service itself is available and working.

Answer (score 1):

In order to invoke a SOAP web service you will need to POST a [XML request in a SOAP envelope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP). That's what the generated classes using `WebReference` do behind the scenes. Unless you have a compelling reason you should never invoke a SOAP web service using the low level classes such as HttpWebRequest but generate a proxy from the WSDL using `Add WebReference`.

Take a look at [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972326.aspx). Also note that classic ASMX web services is now considered a deprecated technology and should be replaced by [WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663324.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You are trying a pre-`WCF` web service.
If migrating to a `WCF` service is an option, you can map the service to [RESTful enpoints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3095736/customize-wcf-service-endpoint-address-in-iis-host).

[REST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer) (Representational State Transfer) is used (among other options) to describe function calls in URL structures, without additional content such as SOAP.